# Transition on pie-chart resize in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition, pie-chart

I am looking for an example on how to make a transition for a pie-chart resize (arc's paths). I have been looking at [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/1346410) but I still don't know how to modify it to make the transition on the resize. So far I am able to resize the pie-chart by changing the outerRadius  (and innerRadius) of the arc object, but no luck with the transition. [Here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/emepyc/VYud2/8/) I am working on.

```
arc.innerRadius(newInnerRad)
   .outerRadius(newOuterRad);

path.transition().duration(500).attrTween("d", arcTween);

function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works if you create `arcTween` inline and add an interpolator for the radius -- see [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYud2/11/).

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks! I am trying to figure out why arcTween has to be inlined. I tried `func(a){arcTween.call(this, a, newRadius)}` but without success. It is not a big issue, but I would like to understand it.

Comment: The tween function needs to be created inline to reflect the changing values of the radius -- if you created it like before, it would only get the radius once at the start. Instead of defining `arcTween` once, you're now defining it again and again, once for each update. This is not the only way of doing it though -- you could save the radius values with the data (similar to the angles) and then get the values from there in the tween function. I prefer this way though as I find it easier to understand.

Comment: Lots of your answers helping me today Lars... can you explain what the ` var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a)` is doing? I can't understand how you can interpolate 2 objects and how that affects the animation?

Comment: @Ian See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#d3_interpolate) -- it creates a function that gives values between two numbers in this case which you need to determine the correct value for the current state of the animation.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yeah absolutely - but the parameters here are 2 objects being passed into  interpolate not 2 numbers - that's what is confusing me

Comment: D3 is smart enough to "decompose" objects and interpolate the components individually.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: So it interpolate's all the values on the objects? So given `{ a: 0, b: 0 }` and `{ a: 1, b: 1 }` it'd interpolate both properties auto-magically? If so that makes a lot more sense :)

Comment: Yes, see the doc for `.interpolateObject()`.